# Node.js express nested routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Node.js and Express and have tried to go through some of the tutorials.  I am able to get basic routing working one level deep (e.g., `http://localhost/help`), but I'm having trouble getting it to work two levels deep (e.g., `http://localhost/help/test`).

Here are the relevant lines in app.js:

```
var help = require('./routes/help');

// also tried this
//var help_test = require('./routes/help/test');

var app = express();
app.use('/help', help);
app.use('/help/test', help.test);

// also tried this
//app.use('/help/test', test);
//app.use('/help/test', help_test);
```

Under the routes directory I have two files: index.js and test.js.

The index.js consists of:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('help');
});

module.exports = router;
```

The test.js file consists of:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('help test!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Right now I can't start the server due to the configuration in app.js, but any changes I make so that I can start it results in a 404 error when I try to hit `http://localhost/help/test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some of your confusion is coming from the `require` in `app.js`.  Let's look at this line:

```
var help = require('./routes/help');
```

That line loads the module in `routes/help.js`. This file is non-existent In your current configuration. Rename your `./routes/index.js` file to `./routes/help.js`.

Since the above file will only handle routes prefixed with `/help` and not `/help/test`, will need to have an additional `require`:

```
var help_test = require('./routes/test');
```

Your `app.js` file should now have the following:

```
var help = require('./routes/index');
var help_test = require('./routes/test');

var app = express();
app.use('/help', help);
app.use('/help/test', help_test);
```

It should be noted that since your `help_test` module defines a path at `/test`, and you "`use`" it at `/help/test`, the final path of that route will be: `/help/test/test`.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's answer got me on the right track, but I ended up with a slightly different solution using his answer that I wanted to post:

In app.js I have:

```
var help = require('./routes/help');
var help_test = require('./routes/help/test');
....
app.use('/help', help);
app.use('/help/test', help_test);
```

Under the `/routes` directory I have this structure:

```
routes
|-- help
    |-- index.js
    |-- test.js
```