# nested routing like namespace in node.js

Tags: router

I would like to nested the routes using router like we did using namespace ->

```
app.namespace('/', function () {
    app.get('/', main.index);
    app.get('contact', main.contact);
    app.get('about', main.about);
});
/* user */
app.namespace('/user', function () {
    app.get('login', user.login);
    app.get('logout', user.logout);
    // an example of namespace in namespace
    app.namespace('/settings', function () {
        app.get('/', user.settings);
        app.get('profile', user.profile);
    });
    /* REST CRUD */
    //read
    app.get('/:id?', user.read); // if is not set, go to user profile
    //create
    app.post('/', user.add);
    //update
    app.put('/', user.update);
    //remove
    app.delete('/', user.destroy);
});
```

I just want to nest the routes same as above but using routers. How???

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution and explaining here...

In app.js file :-

var express = require('express');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.use('/', routes);

In ./routes/index.js

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
// Home page
.....
});

router.get('/navigation1', function(req, res) {
// Nav1 page
.....
});

& more navigations.....

---

I am giving here some links. Check it out...

https://scotch.io/tutorials/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4

[Node.js express nested routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002342/node-js-express-nested-routes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-namespace-routes

```js
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('express-namespace-routes');
const app = express();
 
routes.prefix('/user', (user) => {
  user.post('/', (req, res) => res.send(''));
  user.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(''));
  user.get('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(''));
  user.delete('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(''));
  user.put('/:id', (req, res) => res.send(''));
 
  user.prefix('/settings', (settings) => {
    settings.post('/', (req, res) => res.send(''));
  });
});
 
app.use(routes);
```